# How can I convert a variable of type CLLocation to String?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm using CoreLocation to get a `user's location` and I'm trying to store that location inside of a `String`

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        currentLoc = location // Set location to currentLoc string
        print("Current location: \(location)")
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The question: How can I convert a type of `CLLocation` to a `String`?

Comment: Why? A CLLocation is _not_ a string. And where's your attempt to convert the CLLocation _into_ a String? I don't see you doing it. It isn't even clear what the question is; all you do is show some code. So what? What's the problem?

Comment: @matt I know that a CLLocation is not a string, my question is "How can I convert a **CLLocation into a String?**". I'll edit the question title to clarify that.

Comment: If `location` is a CLLocation, you would say `String(location)`. Is this a trick question? What's the hard part?

Comment: No hard part, that's all that I needed. I just started iOS dev yesterday, while it is a beginner question I don't see a reason for the down vote.

Comment: My guess is that, if you're going to ask questions for every trivial bit of Swift that you don't know, you'll be getting a _lot_ of downvotes. May I suggest that you _learn_ Swift before you use it?

Comment: You're right that this was probably an extremely basic Swift concept that I was asking for, this app's only purpose is to only get a location to send to a server and play from an audio file on the web, the rest is handled on a Node server. I didn't think a small project like this justified learning the entire language first, as this is also my way of learning, by working on projects. I'll avoid asking similar questions in the future.

Comment: You needn't avoid it. You can be upvoted too. It's crowdsourced! But my advice stands; you don't have to take it.